# OpenGL won't render with top left coordinates

Tags: opengl, coordinates, lwjgl, slick2d

I got my projection matrix setup with glOrtho() like this:

```
glOrtho(-Application.HALF_WIDTH, Application.HALF_WIDTH, -Application.HALF_HEIGHT, Application.HALF_HEIGHT, 1, -1);
```

So, when I draw something at origin (0; 0), opengl draws it at the center of the screen. Fine. But now I want to flip the Y coordinate, so I've changed it to this:

```
glOrtho(-Application.HALF_WIDTH, Application.HALF_WIDTH, Application.HALF_HEIGHT, -Application.HALF_HEIGHT, 1, -1);
```

And when I try to draw at (0; 0) (or at any position), it gives a black screen.

What could cause this problem?
p.s. i'm using lwjgl

Comment: If you have backface culling enabled, note that inverting the y-axis changes the winding order.

Comment: oh, indeed. setting glFontFace(GL_CCW) solved it. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When changing the orientation of the y-axis, also the winding order of the primitives changes. So if backface culling is enabled, one has to adjust the winding order by setting it with

```
glFontFace(GL_CCW)
```